# identifier "PLVGROUP" is undefined afxcmn.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2015 project which uses the afxcmn header and is having a lot of "is undefined" errors.

I read in the documentation those data types are included in commctrl.h which is already included in the Visual Studio project as external dependency.

```
// Adds a group to the control.
AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int InsertGroup(_In_ int index, _In_ PLVGROUP pgrp);

// Sets information about the specified group (by ID) in the control.
AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int SetGroupInfo(_In_ int iGroupId, _In_ PLVGROUP pGroup);

// Retrieves information for the specified group in the control.
AFX_ANSI_DEPRECATED int GetGroupInfo(_In_ int iGroupId, _Out_ PLVGROUP pgrp) const;
```

That is some code example of the afxcmn.h which gives those errors.

I dont know if I have to configure something else in the project to include the commctrl header

Comment: `#include <commctrl.h>`?

Comment: yup, the first thing I tried of course, not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are IntelliSense errors generated by Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 5):

yes, PLVGROUP is defined in commctrl.h, but it depends on WINVER

`#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXP)`

that means WINVER >= 501, see:

error-Direktive: MFC does not support WINVER less than 0x0501.  Please change the definition of WINVER in your project properties or precompiled header.

So I had to change my stdafx.h

    `//#define WINVER 0x0500
    #define WINVER NTDDI_WINXP //0x05010000`

Answer (score 1):

My environment is Windows 10 1903/VS2017

I don't know exactly why, but this solves the problem for me:

FYI, this is the original stdafx.h in my project that produce the error in the question:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef VC_EXTRALEAN
#define VC_EXTRALEAN        // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#endif


// Modify the following defines if you have to target a platform prior to the ones specified below.
// Refer to MSDN for the latest info on corresponding values for different platforms.
#ifndef WINVER              // Allow use of features specific to Windows 95 and Windows NT 4 or later.
#define WINVER 0x0400       // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows 98 and Windows 2000 or later.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Allow use of features specific to Windows NT 4 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400 // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows 98 and Windows 2000 or later.
#endif                      

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS          // Allow use of features specific to Windows 98 or later.
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410   // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows Me or later.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE           // Allow use of features specific to IE 4.0 or later.
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0400    // Change this to the appropriate value to target IE 5.0 or later.
#endif

#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS  // some CString constructors will be explicit

......
```

after adding these two lines bellow "#pragma once" the problem is solved:

```
#define WINVER 0x0603
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0603
```

Only adding the first line still produce those errors.